# How to prevent rounding up float numbers in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Maybe this is a dumb question, but I really can't get it. For some reason float values in my program get rounded up during the assignment statement.

Here is the code:

```
Float64 time,test;

for( Shot *sh in _arrayOfShots)
{
    time = sh.bFrameTime; 
    // right here time variable gets value rounded up to 2 decimal places
    // for example: if sh.bFrameTime = 81.919998 => time = 81.92

    NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:time];

    test = [num floatValue];

    [edgeTime addObject:num];
}

// this is my Shot object structure

@interface Shot : NSObject
{
    int bFrame;
    int eFrame;

     Float64 bFrameTime;
}
```

If anyone knows how to deal with this, please give me hint!

Thank you!

Comment: how do you check what it was and what it is?

Comment: I guess you can see the values in a debugger ;)

Comment: You check both values in the debugger?

Comment: yup:) I guess the problem was what Hot Licks explained...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 81.919998 => time = 81.92

is not "rounded up to two decimal places".  The difference in the two is 0.000002, a change in magnitude of 0.0000000244, or about 8 decimal places.  If your source value is single-precision float then it only has 7 decimal places of accuracy.  (But you didn't show the declaration of that so we can't tell.)

The difference could also have to do with how you displayed the two values, as NSLog does a modicum of rounding.

Comment: What declaration did he not show? I vote for the presentation hypothesis (hence my comment to the original post).

Comment: Yeah, I missed that he had the declaration below the other code.  So it's probably just presentation.  NSLog will round like this.

Comment: Guys...I'm looking at the values of time in a debugger same for the actual values inside of the Shot object...and they differ...as for your answer above saying about 7 decimal places of accuracy, I will check it now on a couple of other values.

Comment: so just went through some other cases 126.040001 turns into 126.04, 127.160004 into 127.16 and 159.119995 into 159.12

Comment: @EugeneGordin -- Yep, all cases where you see about 8 digits of accuracy.  Print the values with a format statement:  `NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%14.12f", time]);`, eg.

Answer (score 0):

Add an if statement where you check if the rounded number is larger than the initial number, if so subtract it by 1

Comment: I've reread your statement five times now, and I still can't tell what the hell you're talking about.

Comment: Probavly misread, I thought you wanted to round down to a whole number